# How do you disable an item in a custom menu in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating an add-on and I want to disable the first menu item in my menu in `DocumentApp` to display my title. Is it possible? Here is my code:

```js
function onOpen(){
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi()

  ui.createMenu("My First Add-On!")
  .addItem("My First Add-On","blankFunction")        //This is the menu item that is disabled
  .addItem("Etc.","etc()")
  .addItem("Etc.","etc()")
  .addItem("Etc.","etc()")
  .addToUi()
}
```

Edit: My the question above doesn't solve my problem as I am doing this on using `DocumentApp` and the question specified is `SpreedsheetApp` which is different.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible; see this response from 2016: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41404058/5415398

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable SpreadsheetApp.addMenu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403907/how-to-disable-spreadsheetapp-addmenu-item)